# I'm unable to obtain the bearer token when using oAuth 2.0 in webapi c#

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, webapi, bearer-token, bad-request

Here is the snippet of code that I'm trying to add but this is giving the response as BadRequest

```
var client = new RestClient("https://service.endpoint.com/api/oauth2/token");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=abc&client_secret=123", ParameterType.RequestBody);
 request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer <access_token>");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Can someone post your answer if you know

I have tried to get the Bearer token but the response is throwing as BadRequest

Is there some header that I'm missing - if yes can you please help`